# If then statements with two indices in Magma software

Tags: math-software, magma-cas

In Magma a single variable functions can be created for use, say,

```
f:= func< n | n lt 2 select 2 else Self(n-1)*Self(n)+1 >;
[f(n): n in [0..12]];
```

These are easily modified and ready to use. This question is about either creating a function of two variables or an if-then statement. For example

```
f:= func< n, k | (n eq 0 and k eq 0) select 1 else (k eq 0) select 2 else (k eq n) select 4 else Self(n-1, k-1) + Self(n-1, k) >;
```

and (this example gives the error message " User error: syntax error at end of input ")

```
f:= function(n,k);
  if n eq 0 and k eq 0 then 1;
  elif k eq 0 then 2;
  elif k eq n then 4;
  else Self(n-1, k-1) + Self(n-1, k);
end if;
[[f(n,k): k in [0..n]]: n in [0..5]];
```

should work but it seems that maybe Magma does not compute two variable (index) self referenced (recurrence) function. Is this the case or is there a workable model in which the if-then/function can be computed?

Comment: The third example is one that is speculative, since I seem to be missing how to make the if-then code(s) work. The last two examples are of the forms given in the  [Magma Document](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to note: the `Self` command is used when recursively constructing a sequence, to refer to entries in the sequence under construction. But it is not used in creating recursive functions. You want to either name the function (using the alternate `function f` construction method below), or when you are constructing a function that has not yet been assigned a name you can refer to it using `$$`.

Third function should be

```
function f(n,k)
  if n eq 0 and k eq 0 then
    val := 1;
  elif k eq 0 then
    val := 2;
  elif k eq n then
    val := 4;
  else
    val := f(n-1,k-1) + f(n-1,k);
  end if;
  return val;
end function;
```

or

```
function f(n,k)
  return (n eq 0 and k eq 0) select 1 else (k eq 0) select 2 else (n eq k) select 4 else f(n-1, k-1) + f(n-1, k);
end function;
```

or

```
function f(n,k)
  return case< <n,k> | <0,0> : 1, <n,0> : 2, <n,n> : 4, default: f(n-1, k-1) + f(n-1, k)>;
end function;
```

Using the function definition you were using previously, you could also write

```
f := function(n,k)
  return case< <n,k> | <0,0> : 1, <n,0> : 2, <n,n> : 4, default: $$(n-1, k-1) + $$(n-1, k)>;
end function;
```

Comment: Having a good example to see how to set up and close a function is a huge help towards a better understanding of Magma. Thanks for the learning examples.

Comment: @Leucippus Glad I could help